# Frequency of word length, program only opens the cmd, but does nothing, C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on an assignment for a long time. I've tried a lot of solutions, yet i cannot figure out a way to make it work. My assignment is to create a code that reads in the text from a file and displays the frequency of lengths of the words. That is, if it reads in "My name is Jon" it should display "1 = 0, 2 = 2, 3 = 1, 4 = 1" (first number being the length of the word and the second is the frequency). I have written a code that i'm quite sure is close to working, but it does not work, it doesn't even show errors or nothing, it just opens the cmd and does nothing. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int NextWordLength(void); //function prototypes
void DisplayFrequencyTable(const int Words[]);

const int WORD_LENGTH = 16; // global constant for array

int main()
{
    int WordLength;  //actual length of word 0 to x
    int NumOfWords[WORD_LENGTH] = {0}; //array hold # of lengths of words

    WordLength=NextWordLength();
    while (WordLength)  //continue to loop until no word i.e. 0
    {
        (WordLength <= 14) ? (++NumOfWords[WordLength]):(++NumOfWords[15]);
        WordLength=NextWordLength();
    }
    DisplayFrequencyTable(NumOfWords);
}

int NextWordLength(void)
{
    fstream fin ("in.txt", ios::in);
    char Ch;
    int EndOfWord = 0; //tells when we have read in one word
    int LengthOfWord = 0;

    Ch = cin.get();  //get first character

    while (!cin.eof() && !EndOfWord)
    {
        while (isspace(Ch) || ispunct(Ch)) //skips elading white spaces
        {
            Ch = cin.get(); //and leading punctation marks
        }
        if (isalnum(Ch)) // if character is a letter or number
        {
            ++LengthOfWord;
        }
        Ch = cin.get(); //get next character
        if((Ch=='-')&&(cin.peek()=='\n')) //check for hyphenated word over two lines
        {
            Ch = cin.get();
            Ch = cin.get();

        }
        if ((Ch=='-')&&(isalpha(cin.peek()))) // check for hyphenated word in one line
        {
            ++LengthOfWord; //count the hyphen as part of word
            Ch = cin.get(); //get next character
        }
        if((Ch=='\n')&& (isalpha(cin.peek()))) //check for apostrophe in the word
        {
            ++LengthOfWord; //count apostrophe in word length
            Ch = cin.get(); //and get the next letter
        }
        if(isspace(Ch) || ispunct(Ch) || cin.eof()) //is it end of word
        {
            EndOfWord++;
        }
    }
    return LengthOfWord;
}


void DisplayFrequencyTable(const int Words[])
{
    int TotalWords = 0, TotalLength = 0;
    cout << "\nWord Length Frequency\n";
    cout << "------------ ----------\n";

    for (int i=1; i<=WORD_LENGTH-1; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(4)<<i<<setw(18)<<Words[i]<<endl;
        TotalLength += (i*Words[i]);
        TotalWords += Words[i];
    }
    cout << "\nAverage word length is ";

    if (TotalLength)
    {
        cout << float(TotalLength)/TotalWords << endl;
    }
    else cout << 0 << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Try running it in debug in your IDE. I bet you one of your `while` loops are stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: To start with, the `NextWordLength` function opens the file from the beginning each call, so if the first word in the file is of non-zero length you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Any idea on how i can fix this? I can't figure it out, damn this task is stressing me out so much. :s I;ve tried opening the file in the main function, but then it doesn;t allow me using fin's in NextWordLength.

Comment: Your debugger can help.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this code, can't figure out the mistake. I realise it's an infinite loop error but i have no idea how to fix it. If i open the file anywhere else but at the NextWordLength, it doesn't let me use the fin operation. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Open the fstream in main, pass it into NextWordLength as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Despite declaring `fin` in `NextWordLength`, your function never uses it.  Instead, it reads from `cin`, so your program is expecting you to type in text for it to process.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, but it diesn't work even if i hange all the cins with fins. It still opens the cmd and does nothing.

Comment: @user3780302: I believe [Joachim Pileborg's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436365/frequency-of-word-length-program-only-opens-the-cmd-but-does-nothing-c/24436422?noredirect=1#comment37809457_24436365) explains that part.